# pip install pdfminer error (python 2 on Windows)

Tags: python, pip, pdfminer

When I run pip install pdfminer using Python 2.7 on Windows Server 2012, I got the following error :

```
Running setup.py install for pdfminer ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\python27\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\2\\pip-install-xgbxsi\\pdfminer\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\admin
i~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\2\\pip-install-xgbxsi\\pdfminer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'
"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\2\pip-record-mdl997\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
     cwd: c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\2\pip-install-xgbxsi\pdfminer\
Complete output (24 lines):
running install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\2\pip-install-xgbxsi\pdfminer\setup.py", line 71, in <module>
    'Topic :: Text Processing',
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\2\pip-install-xgbxsi\pdfminer\setup.py", line 11, in run
    from pdfminer.cmapdb import convert_cmap
  File "pdfminer\cmapdb.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .psparser import PSStackParser
  File "pdfminer\psparser.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .utils import choplist
  File "pdfminer\utils.py", line 219, in <module>
    0x00f8, 0x00f9, 0x00fa, 0x00fb, 0x00fc, 0x00fd, 0x00fe, 0x00ff,
  File "pdfminer\utils.py", line 187, in <genexpr>
    PDFDocEncoding = ''.join(chr(x) for x in (
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python27\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\2\\pip-install-xgbxsi\\pdfminer\\setup.py'"'"
'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\2\\pip-install-xgbxsi\\pdfminer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close()
;exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\2\pip-record-mdl997\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

This used to work ... and I have no clue on how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Recently pdfminer [dropped the support](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/commit/2908c7750b99ef21aa3a3b38fc7e01c3a4eb98dd) for Python 2.

You can try using [pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six), this is a fork of pdfminer that it supports both Python 2 and 3. However, the support for Python 2 will be dropped at January, 2020, so it will only buy you a few months.

Full disclosure: I am one of the maintainers of pdfminer.six.

Comment: What's the point of creating a new project (pdfminer.six) that's going to be used only for a couple of months ?
That's just an honest question: I assume it must have been quite a lot of work to integrate six usage, and now support for Python2 is dropped ... so what's the point of the project in 2020 compared to the original pdfminer ?
Again, I am just curious about the reasons

Comment: It has been around for a couple of years now.